# PrimeNG treeTable - change default expandedIcon/collapsedIcon

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng, primeng-treetable

I am using **treeTable** from **primeNG**. I wanted to know how to change default expand and collapse icon.

I tried doing so... but I am not sure if I'm doing it the right way. I just want to replace those default ***expand/collapse icons to plus/minus***. How do I go about?

I tried following.. but it didn't help.

[image]

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-treetablesections-demo-rd3b72?file=src/assets/filesystem.json)

Comment: No, you can't. Source code don't use Node's icon properties. See https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/8838002c0b8697cffb88b90b1c2419ac4333a13d/src/app/components/treetable/treetable.ts#L2878

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how you can replace those icons in your CSS:

```
::ng-deep .pi-chevron-right:before {
  content: "\e90d";
}

::ng-deep .pi-chevron-down:before {
  content: "\e90f";
}
```

See [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-treetablesections-demo-4mjg4e?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using primeng 16 you can use the following template customization:

```
    <ng-template pTemplate="togglericon" let-open>
      <span *ngIf="open" class="pi pi-minus"></span>
      <span *ngIf="!open" class="pi pi-plus"></span>
    </ng-template>
```

Just place it inside your p-treetable element.
The 'let-open' just gives you access to the implicit boolean value of the context; you could change 'open' to whatever you want to refer to it as. 
This probably works on earlier versions of primeng but I didn't test it.
Link to template customizations in the API:
https://primeng.org/treetable#api.treetable.templates